# How can I place an html element (div or paragraph) in the center of 2 boostrap columns?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have some text in the vertical and horizontal middle of 2 boostrap columns full height and with equal weight. The outcome should be like in the picture below.

[image describing div overlaying columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4tMz.png)

I tried to add a  inside the main container but outside of the columns, but that would render it outside of the two boostrap columns. I also tried to use the z-index but that did not work too.

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-6 left-side h-100">
        <h2 class='h2-mainpage'><span class="initial"><strong>D</strong></span>IGITAL <span class="initial"><strong>W</strong></span>ORKSHOPS</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 right-side h-100">
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="centertext">Elevating Passions through technology</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Move `.centertext` to be inside the `.row.h-100`
- Make `.container-fluid > .row` a relative container
- Absolute center `.centertext` using a `transform`

```css
/* Decoration — ignore */
h2 { text-align: center; }

.container-fluid>.row {
  position: relative;
}

.centertext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2em 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-6 left-side h-100">
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed delectus inventore nemo. Odit qui in voluptatibus, quasi eius architecto deleniti iusto quidem id blanditiis aspernatur corporis soluta placeat quis voluptates!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 right-side h-100">
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, ab in. Nulla modi explicabo laudantium sequi, nesciunt vero ratione tempore est! Ipsa quas minima aliquam eius, quia iste consequatur sapiente!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="centertext">Elevating Passions through technology</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvudLo4r/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked well !! Really appreciate it!